# Google finds my real IP even when the proxy is on

Tags: vpn, ip, proxy, socks

I am using a proxy application [sshuttle] on my linux for ssh tunneling. The websites such as whatismyip.com or browserleaks.com/ip echo my ip as expected. But Googling "my ip" on Chromium returns my real IP. WebRTC is also disabled by an extension.

I have even tried the incognito session to make sure that it's not stored in the the browser's cache but had not change. I have also tried other proxy applications. The only thing that worked for me was tun2socks.
What is missing that Google has still access to my real IP?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chromium - I edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use this tool: http://rafa.eu.org/http_test.php3 - I wrote it quite a time ago to analyze proxy issue. The output is in Polish, but there's not much to read :)

On the top, you get the information what is the IP and domain address you are connecting from, as seen by the server. This should be your proxy address.

However, if your proxy is a **non-anonymous** proxy, the page will inform you (in red) that you are using a proxy. Then you will see a copy of request headers that are sent to the server from your browser, and there should be two lines highlighted in red that allow the server to detect a proxy: `Via:` and `X-Forwarded-For:`. The latter contains your original IP address.

Non-anonymous proxies usually add these lines to the request. Anonymous proxies don't.

(The tool also checks whether your browser sent a "Referer:" header and marks this in blue, but this is unrelated to your question).

Comment: Thank you. I checked it out. In accordance to your explanation the proxy is anonymous.

Comment: So you must be using some service that connects to Google bypassing the proxy.

Comment: Or maybe it's just Chromium itself that connects to Google bypassing the proxy? Did you try another browser?

Comment: That's right I think Chromium is creating tun or something for accessing web. I didn't have this issue of Firefox.